# Can I keep Mono from hanging up when I close my SSH connection?

Tags: linux, arch-linux, mono-framework

I have a headless Linux server that I connect to through SSH. I recently started using it, in addition to its normal tasks, to host a [game server][1] written in C# with Mono. It performs admirably! However, if I disconnect from my SSH session, it hangs up and game clients disconnect.

To start the game server, I run the command `mono KMPServer.exe`. After this, the server software starts and displays configuration information - however, the game server is not running until I type `/start`.

I can't use `nohup` because of that - the process of starting the server involves first running it with mono, then interacting with it with it to issue a "`/start`" command. Interestingly, I can't background the process either (Is this normal for Mono?).

Is there any way to run it in a way to keep the game server from closing when I disconnect the SSH session?

Summary:

- The server software (dead link removed) is a third-party multiplayer server (part of a mod) for [Kerbal Space Program](https://kerbalspaceprogram.com/).
- The Linux server is running Arch Linux x86_64.
- The installed Mono version is 3.2.3

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sounds like you should be able to use a screen session. If you are unfamiliar with the screen tool, check out the man pages or visit [Screen Command Examples: Get Control of Linux / Unix Terminal](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/07/screen-command-examples/).

First, install it with `pacman -S screen`. Then start a new session with `screen mono KMPServer.exe`, perform all you need to do and detach the session with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>. If you need to attach the session again, use `screen -x`.

Comment: Ah, I hadn't thought of that! It works perfectly!